# Sublime Text Search and Replace

Tags: regex, sublime-text

I want to replace all my

```
$r->fields[variables]
```

to

```
$r->fields["variables"]
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Could you show us more test cases with your attempts to solve your problem?

Comment: Please [read up on how to ask a good question here](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `\$\w+->\w+\[\K\w+`
- Replace: `"$0"`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$          # $ sign
\w+         # 1 or more word character
->          # literally
\w+         # 1 or more word character
\[          # [ character
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\w+         # 1 or more word character (you can use .+? if your variable contains other character than word character)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

> [image]

**Screenshot (after):**

> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much 

Can please tell me the solution for my other question also? I dont understand regex at all - maybe im too stupid... :(

Comment: @susi: Find: `\w+\(\K\w+` Replace: `"$0"`. If you have another cases, please, edit your question with example text and expected result. If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @susi If you have  a new question, you need to ask a new question. You should not post a new question as an answer where you are effectively just asking question upon question upon question that focuses on latching onto one answerer doing work for you.